# call Graph using delegated permissions with Azure API management in between

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-management

So, I need to provide some info from MS Graph about the current logged in user, but there's also API Management layer in between.
This is how it looks like

```
3rd party app <-> API Management <-> My funcions <-> Graph
```

The 3rd party app is currently requesting info using application access, so for user xy I can also simply call the `/users/xy` graph call and forward the response. The idea is that the app never has permissions to call graph directly.

Now, the developer teams want to use the "current user" endpoints like: `/me/calendar/events` while our security wants to keep the API Management layer in between.

Is it possible? If yes, please give me some hint how to implement this, without giving access to the 3d party team.